# Can a preposition be used without an object?

Tags: prepositions

I'm confused about the role of "from" in the sentence

> Where I'm from, nobody talks to me like that.

According to Merriam-Webster, "from" is always a preposition (unlike e.g. "on", which can be a preposition, an adverb or an adjective.) But if "from" is a preposition in the sentence above, then where is its object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things involved here.

The first is that Yes, prepositions are often employed 'intransitively', without an object: for instance, the prepositions<sup>†</sup> in verbal idioms like *sit down* and *stand up*.

The second is that although *where* ordinarily stands for an entire preposition phrase—*the store **where** I buy my beer* is equivalent to *the store **at which** I buy my beer*—the implied preposition is often supplemented with an express preposition. Because the 'default' interpretation of *where* is that it designates a static location, the supplemental preposition is almost obligatory when *where* designates not a static location but the origin or a goal of some motion. For instance,

> Where I am *designates my present location, but*
>
> Where I am **from** *adds the preposition* from *to indicate that* where *designates my origin, not my location*.

But supplemental prepositions are not limited to situations like this: they are also used with ordinary locatives, sometimes with a particular idomatic sense. Back in the 60s, for instance, the phrase *where it's **at*** was a common designation for clubs and other venues regarded as especially fashionable:

> They got a little place a-down the track
>   The name of the place is I like it like that
>   You take Sally and I'll take Sue
>   And we're gonna rock away all of our blues
>   Come on, come on, let me show you where it's at
>   The name of the place is I like it like that.
>        —'I Like It Like That', Chris Kenner

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Traditional grammar called them 'adverbs' and some modern grammarians call them 'particles'.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! In "sit down" and "stand up", "down" and "up" are clearly adverbs, not prepositions. I suppose that makes me a traditionalist. In any case, this is not what I meant when I mentioned prepositions in my question.
So is the word "from" in my example sentence also a preposition in the traditionalist sense?

Comment: @animis [Here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/382140/24489)'s one of the arguments for treating these words as prepositions. *CGEL* treats the matter at considerable length in Ch. 7, §2.4, 612-617.

Comment: Thank you. I had a look at CGEL and found it very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence, "Where are you from?" the pronoun "where" is clearly the object of the preposition. The same applies to the phrase, "Where I am from..."

The traditional form of the question would have been "From where have you come?" "From where" avoids the dangling preposition at the end of the sentence. "Have you come", is past perfect because at the time when the speaker is speaking, the action (come) is complete.

By modern standards, the rule against the dangling preposition is dismissed as an artificial attempt to impose Latin grammar on English, and we often prefer to refer to "being from somewhere" as a current state of being rather than "coming from somewhere" as a completed action. Therefore, the common question, "Where are you from?"