# X is necessary to do something

Tags: meaning

Is it true that 1 and 2 are wrong? If yes, why

> 1 Bad news is necessary to grapple with.
>
> 2 Bad news is something that becomes necessary to grapple with.
>
> 3 It is necessary to grapple with bad news.

Comment: How do you grapple with bad news? Your third sentence makes the most sense.

Comment: It's from a  dictionary. Why are the first two wrong?

Comment: What aspect of learning English are you asking about? This reads as a request for proof-reading as-is. Please edit your question to explain what you really want, or delete. Thanks

Comment: What I really want is understand why the first 2 are wrong since the syntax is correct. Are you having a hard time seeing it? Why is it that "Bad news is difficult to digest" is correct while "Bad news is necessary to grapple with." is wrong. They have the same word order. I am baffled by your request.

Comment: Why didn't you tell us which dictionary it came from? I've found sentence (2) (with _it_ instead of _that_) in [Cambridge Dictionary's](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grapple) definition of _grapple_. I didn't say that the first two were wrong, just that (3) made the most sense to me.

Comment: But 1 and 2 are likely to be wrong. "Bad news is necessary to grapple with (what?)"

Comment: As I said, _Bad news is something **it** becomes necessary to grapple with_ is in the dictionary. The object of _grapple with_ is _something_, identified as _bad news_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/grapple-with) has an entry for *grapple with something* and labels it as an intransitive phrasal verb. This is a neat way to make the entry, because it is a clear expression that the *something* is an intrinsic part of this phrasal verb; no further object is required. There are many intricacies that can be by-passed because the entry exists as such. There is no entry for *grapple with* alone.

**grapple with something** (phrasal verb)
*to try to deal with or understand a difficult problem or subject*

[Phrasal verbs](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/common-phrasal-verbs/) consist of a base verb used in combination with one or more words that together act as a completely new verb with a meaning separate from those of the original words.

> Wiki entry for [grapple](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grapple):
>
> 1. (intransitive) *To wrestle or tussle.*
> 2. (figurative, with **with**) *To ponder and intensely evaluate a problem; to struggle to deal with*

When used in combination with the preposition *with* (and a noun) the intransitive base verb transforms into a figurative expression.

Example sentences in question:

1. *Bad news is necessary to grapple with.*
2. *Bad news is something that becomes necessary to grapple with.*
3. *It is necessary to grapple with bad news.*

An incomplete version of the phrasal verb *grapple with something* is used in both answers 1 and 2. The *something* is not optional. Only answer 3 uses “bad news” as the *something* in the *grapple with something* combination, so it is the only correct answer.

There is some controversy that surrounds the legitimacy of phrasal verbs. Below are some of the resources I used to research this topic. They can provide more information about their use and place in contemporary writing.

1. StoneyB posted on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124810/can-a-preposition-be-used-without-an-object) about how prepositional phrases and verbs interact.
2. Araucaria on [ELaU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/382126/what-parts-of-speech-are-the-words-pick-up-when-used-as-a-verb/382140#382140) describes the use of compound verbs, not necessarily as phrasal verbs (This served as my introduction to the concept of phrasal verbs).
3. [Grammar Monster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/phrasal_verbs.htm) has a more in-depth  exploration  about phrasal verbs, their history, and when and where it is appropriate to use them.
4. Wiki has an [encyclopedic entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phrasal_verbs) that was also useful.

Note: Please note that I created a separate answer from my previous one because, there may yet be some validity to that approach. This is completely new research that was inspired from reading the answer to a different question that caused me to look at this question in a completely different way. If questions arise, I'd prefer to deal with them separately from each other.